# Is there a case where a stateless method should not be static?

Tags: oop, state

As stateless methods are mostly marked as static, they do not require the instance. But I am wondering whether there could be a case where a stateless method still can be an instance method of a class?
The reason I ask is that I have read some learning materials that mention "stateless and static methods", so I am thinking about the difference.

Comment: Static methods aren't necessarily stateless. They might use/alter class static data.

Comment: @Mat True, I mean then just those really not doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if you want to make use of what is called "Strategy Pattern" in OOP-terms.

For example, if you are programming a little calculator, and you want to apply a binary operation to the two numbers on top of the stack, you want to map user input to instances of the classes `Addition`, `Subtraction`, ..., `Division`, which all implement an interface `BinaryOperator` and have a (stateless!) method `int apply(int firstArg, int secondArg)`.

The basic arithmetic operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` are as stateless as anything can possibly get, but still, you are attaching them to instances of classes.

This is kind-of a canonical example, because whenever you mix OOP with purely functional programming, all objects without mutable state become something like collections of closures, which are essentially the good-old-oop-strategies on methamphetamines.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind: depending on the used language/technology, *static* can be almost an anti-pattern.

In Java for example, *static* is implemented in a way that basically **kills** polymorphism. But *polymorphism* is one of the cornerstones of OOP. You use it to enable yourself to easily add new functionality - by extending some class and *overriding* a certain method. But when using *static*, you directly "link" yourself to that very specific class and method implementation. If you need *different* behaviour, you either have

- change the caller to invoke some *other* method
- change the behaviour of that static method.

And of course: again, in Java, in order to do proper unit testing, *static* can get in your way quickly. And most often, when people find "woha, my code under test calls that static method, and ouch, calling that static method throws up in our unit test environment" - their "answer" is to turn to mocking frameworks that allow to mock static methods (like PowerMock or JMockit). And that can lead to other issues.

Thus: *static* has its place, but depending on your technology stack you should be really careful about using it. *Not having state* is probably thus *necessary, but sufficient* when determining whether some method should be *static* or not.